# Is it possible to make full recursive alias for an entire Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi my question is very weird but necessary.
The database was made by a person who named tables and fields like "EMP.EMPCOD0001". Of course that's a low level work but there is no way to change the system and the guy is supported by the company's owner, and IT needs to work properly.

Is it possible to create a kind of shadow table which links to another with reasonable names like: "employee.id_number" pointing to the crappy table?

Comment: Maybe you could use a view. (Supported by most dbms's.)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for _views_?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: yes I omitted  that information, the database is made in Oracle 12. I need not only alias for the tablename but the table fields too

Comment: Then you will need to create a view for each and every table renaming the table and the columns

Comment: Creating a view is obvious but developers may still continue to use the bad style, even create new code with the bad naming.

Answer (score 3):

Use views, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW emp.GoodName (goodCol1, goodCol2, goodColEtc)
 as SELECT lameCol1, lameCol2, lameColEtc
 from emp.LameName
```

You could put all the views in the dbo schema, but--if it's well thought out or used for security--you might want to maintain the existing schemas.

(Edited to show that columns can be "mapped" as well.)

Comment: (My syntax is for SQL Server)